# Auto off water pump only when tank is full

Tags: switches, relay, water, fluid-pump

The water pump installed at my residence is operated on and off manually through a conventional switch wall socket.

Now, I want the pump to be automatically switched off whenever the tank is 90 percent filled through an external circuit diagram or relay. However, the pump should be operated ON by the manual switch, and only AUTO OFF by the circuit diagram.

Please kindly provide appropriate diagram for the said project and the suitable BUTTON SWITCH TO MANUALLY ON the pump.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the water is below 90% of tank. Then float switch is closed. When NO Push Button is pressed, relay turns ON. Even if NO Push button is released, the relay remains ON. Contacts 6 and 5 closes and latches the (Double Pole Double Throw) relay, to turn it off manually you need to press and release the NC Push Button. When water reaches 90%, the float switch opens and the relay is no longer latched and turns off.

If the tank is 90% full then you cannot use the NO push button to latch the relay. However the motor will run as long as you keep pressing the NO Push Button. If you need to revert to the original setup all you need to do is to use the bypass switch. The bypass switch is your traditional ON and OFF switch. Keep bypass switch in OFF position when you need auto off feature.

Choose appropriate relay rating. Hope this helps.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: But, the switch 1 doesn't come to the original position automatically when the tanky is full. I need the switch 1 to be automatically come to off position. Only when the switch 1 is pressed, the pump will on and as the tank is full, the switch 1 has to restore to it's original position automatically. Any relevant switch available??

Comment: Doesn't your pump have a motor starter?

Comment: Nope. Just closing the switch 1 starts the pump. Thats it.

Comment: I want the switch 1 to restore to it's original position as tanky is full. Please suggest suitable restorable switch for this, and not like conventional switch.

Comment: To be more precise, as switch is pressed, the button should be hold at midway from full position to make the pump on, and automatically return to normal full position when tank is full.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Sure, your diagram is really interesting....